# Derby xsa12 error on DB table that exists.... but doesn't

Tags: derby

I'm not sure what is going on with my derby database, but I seem to have tables that I can can see from the ij interface...

```
ij> show tables in derbytest;
TABLE_SCHEM         |TABLE_NAME                    |REMARKS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
DERBYTEST           |DATATYPETEST                  |
DERBYTEST           |LOCATION                      |
DERBYTEST           |SUIVI                         |
```

now I get the tables description...

```
ij> describe derbytest.datatypetest;
COLUMN_NAME         |TYPE_NAME|DEC&|NUM&|COLUM&|COLUMN_DEF|CHAR_OCTE&|IS_NULL&
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A_DATE              |DATE     |0   |10  |10    |NULL      |NULL      |NO
AN_INT              |INTEGER  |0   |10  |10    |NULL      |NULL      |YES
A_DECIMAL           |DECIMAL  |0   |10  |5     |NULL      |NULL      |YES
A_STRING            |VARCHAR  |NULL|NULL|20    |NULL      |40        |YES
A_SWITCH            |BOOLEAN  |NULL|NULL|1     |NULL      |NULL      |YES
```

So I guess the table exists, but...

```
ij> select * from derbytest.datatypetest;
ERREUR XSAI2 : Le conglomÚrat (1á232) demandÚ n'existe pas.
```

So a quick check to see if the problem is being caused by an 'empty' table..

```
ij> select * from derbytest.suivi;
OBS        |DATE                         |TIME
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

which to me suggests not!

I'm not sure I fully understand the implication of the error message, i found this in the docs

> Table 36. Class XSAI: Store - access.protocol.interface SQLSTATE
>     Message Text XSAI2  The conglomerate () requested does not
>   exist.

which isn't amazingly helpful!
I've had a look at the various API docs for the engine, language, testing and tools, but I don't know where to start to look, any pointers would be helpfull.

It may be related to how I am setting the database, so some quick background.

I connecting to this test DB from a java test class. It gathers info from another datasource (XL of flat file) then drops it into this database (or that is the aim). I am only showing a small 'test' that I may to ensure my connection was working.

I have another schema in this file that has more tables, and they all have this same problem.

Have I not correctly closed a conection and lost data?
Have I somehow inadvertently delected a data file, that contained the missing 'conglomerate'

Any help is greately appreciated.

David.

ps I have other test DB's that I haven't checked to see if they have the same problem.
I'm running java 6 on XP.

edit1: Just checked the other testDB I am using, it contains no tables! I obviously cleaned up after myself. Now where did that cat go ??

Comment: I just noticed I have a column called 'DATE' which is fine, but it is a reserved word? When I created the table I didn't surround the column in backticks, but Derby still allowed me to create a column with this name. I think that is just plain wrong, it should have thrown out an sql error of some sort, at least that is my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is odd behavior, to be sure. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Did you create your table inside a transaction but not yet commit that transaction?

Did you create your table using an in-memory database, in which case it disappears when you close the database?

Did you create your database in one location on the disk, then later connect to a different location with 'create=true', in which case Derby creates a new blank database in the new location?

Did you create your database using one schema, then connect with a different schema?

The error message does suggest some internal damage to the table. The number in parentheses (1a232) is a conglomerate number, which is also used to identify the conglomerate's filename in your filesystem. So you could look in the filesystem and match up the files that are there to the tables in your database (by selecting from sys.sysconglomerates).

You get a conglomerate for the table itself, plus additional conglomerates for each secondary index, both those created by CREATE INDEX and those created by implicit constraints such as UNIQUE or REFERENCES.

If you suspect you have table damage, it's best to restore from a backup. Did you experience any system crashes, disk full events, etc., which might have indicated table damage?

Comment: Bryan, I am running junit tests, so this is a very temp DB, and who knows what nonsense I may be inadvertently doing ;). for now the problem has solved itself as I dropped the tables then re-ran the tests. Everything has worked fine since. (sorry I should have probably made a copy of the DB). Hopefully a glitch on my part, or a time out maybe? I search the sys.sysconglomerates if I come across the problem again